# Selenium Firefox issues on Win7

Tags: java, firefox, windows-7, selenium, jboss-arquillian

I'm running `mvn test` (using Maven 3) on the [arquillian-examples arquillian drone tutorial](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-examples/tree/master/arquillian-drone-tutorial).

I get the following error on Win7 (using jdk 1.6.0.26).

```
14:54:46.002 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
14:55:06.829 ERROR - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and c
lear all session data
java.lang.RuntimeException: Firefox refused shutdown while preparing a profile
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.wai
tForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:367)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.pop
ulateCustomProfileDirectory(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:120)
...
14:55:06.891 INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: Error while
 launching browser on session null
classLoader = WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
...
```

I'd like to either: (a) get firefox working; or (b) get it working in IE. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got around it - but I'm open to a solution that answer the core issue and will mark that as the answer.

I modifed the file here:
`\arquillian-examples\arquillian-drone-tutorial\src\test\resources`

To add:

```
<extension qualifier="selenium">
    <property name="browser">*iexplore</property>
</extension>
```